# compulsory php7.2 settings in ubuntu 18.04 environment for web development

Tags: development, php7

I have ubuntu 18.04 development environment. Is this compulsory to make change on the following lines below in php.ini file to run environment properly?

```
$ sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
```

Changes are ..

```
  file_uploads = On
  allow_url_fopen = On
  memory_limit = 256M
  upload_max_filesize = 100M
  max_execution_time = 360
  date.timezone =
```

Thanks..

Comment: Why do you believe you have to change this?

Comment: Every environment is different and you would be in a better position to answer the question than us. Do you need to upload files as large as 100MB? Do you have processes that take 6 minutes to run? If so, then maybe these settings are accurate.

Comment: I found this settings during Installing Drupal 8 following this link [link](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-drupal-cms-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-with-nginx-mariadb-php-7-2-and-lets-encrypt-ssl-tls-certificates/). @vidarlo

Comment: Thanks @Matigo. But what is general or standard settings for php.ini file in my ubuntu 18.04 environment?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want to know the suggested values for a Drupal installation? Or do you want to know the default values that come with an installation of PHP?

Comment: Thanks @Matigo Exactly I just want to know the suggested values for a Drupal 8.9.dev or Drupal 9 dev installation.

Comment: As this is a *development* environment you're asking about, you will probably want to drop the `max_execution_time` down to 30 or some such and have all the other numbers match the production environment.  A dev machine is rarely as busy as a production server, so allowing execution time to be crazy high can result in really poor performance on the real machine. That said, as a developer, it's on you to know when settings should be raised or lowered, and what performance metrics are to be adhered to.